# Android actionbar popup menu

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to accomplish a popup menu [Popup Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiZQ2.png)

for my android app, with a custom app bar/ toolbar placed at the bottom.

I have already tried with the options menu and custom alert dialog but seems there must be a simpler way, am I missing something?

What is the best-suited way to achieve this menu design?

Do I need to use custom navigation drawer if not then please help.

Edit : As @Blackbelt suggested Bottom Sheet Dialog, which looks fine but it is covering my bottom app bar and I am not able to set any Margin Bottom for it. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: that looks like a Bottom Sheet dialog

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can you please tell me how to add bottom margin to the dialog as it is covering my App bar?